# How push exit status before _exit in gas?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, calling-convention

From this tutorial:
[elf tutorial](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)
having this:

```
.text
    .globl _start
_start:
    pushq $42
    call _exit
```

I do not know, wheter exit status should be `push`ed, or `mov`ed to `%ebp`, but from the tutorial, they have this.
compiled:

```
as a.s -o a.o
cc -Wall -s -nostartfiles a.o
./a.out; echo $?
144 #not 42
```

So what should I do to see `42` as exit status?

Comment: The [64 bit calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) does not use the stack to pass this argument. Do `mov $42, %edi` instead.

Comment: x86-64 SysV passes the first up to 6 args in registers, not the stack.  Porting tutorials from 32 to 64-bit makes things more complicated.

Comment: Yeah you might be better off using `as --32` and `gcc -m32` to create 32 bit program so you can use the tutorial unchanged.

Comment: but if as assemble with `--32` and then compile the same way with `-m32`, then many errors that incompatible glibc and that compiler cannot find glibc for x32. How to do it?

Comment: Install `gcc-multilib` if you want to link 32-bit programs against libc.  (Your distro might call it something else.)  This program chould be built with `gcc -m32 -nostartfiles a.s`.  Don't use `-s`, stripping debug info is not helpful when you want to debug it.  (You'll have to change `pushq` to just `push`, or `pushl` if you want to be explicit about operand-size.)

Comment: @PeterCordes or I can do `ld -m elf_i386 -o a.out a.o`

Comment: You could, yes, if you don't need libc.  But once you know what commands the `gcc` front end runs for `gcc -m32 -static -nostdlib`, you can use it to save typing by running `as` and `ld` for you.  Or use `-no-pie -nostartfiles` to link libc.

Comment: @PeterCordes, you always says gcc *front* end. Where is, and how can i use `gcc` *backend*?

Comment: The GCC back-end is the optimizing compiler proper, which reads high-level language and emits assembly language.  For C, it's `cc1`.  e.g. on my system, `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/cc1`.  It's invoked as a separate process by `/usr/bin/gcc`, which you can see if you run `gcc -v foo.c`.  The `gcc` front-end runs it, `as`, and/or `ld` (via collect2) depending on what inputs you give it.

Comment: @PeterCordes so the optimizations done by `-O{1,2,3}`, are done by the backend?

Comment: Yes, of course.  GCC can't optimize asm source input, only high-level languages like C, C++, Fortran, etc.